# imagemagick-montage vertically decrease distance between photos

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-montage

I would like to remove the vertical distance between the photos, i used the following command:
montage -geometry 640x480 +0+0 *.JPG montage5.jpg

but no matter what the gap is still presents between the photos. i checked they are all in the same result was originally as well, after run the command above, all the images became 640x480 so i don't know the reason why there is a gap

[image: pix-art]

Comment: Try `magick montage -geometry +0+0 *.jpg montage.jpg`